# Given a base class how do I find the most specialized subclasses of it?

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, subclass

I can find all the classes that are subclasses of BaseClass with something like

```
var subclasses = Assembly
   .GetAssembly(typeof(BaseClass))
   .GetTypes()
   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
```

Now, how do I select only the most specialized subclasses? That is, the leaf-nodes, the ones with no subclasses of their own.

Comment: No. Not yet at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subclasses.Where(c => !subclasses.Any(c2 => c == c2.BaseType))
```

This will be faster is you make a HashSet of BaseTypes.

This only works because `BaseClass` is in the same assembly; otherwise, it would inconrrectly catch intermediate classes which inherit from an intermediate class in a different assembly.
The more general solution would be to check `IsAssignableFrom` against every other subclass.

Comment: Note that due to deferred execution, for each type you're iterating all of the types in the assembly and filtering those that are subclasses of the base type.  That makes it *very* important to stick `subclasses` into a collection first.  As you said, `HashSet` would be the preferred option.

Comment: @Servy: Very good point.  If you don't want to use a HashSet, use `.ToList()` and `RemoveAll()`.

Comment: This returns the first level of subclasses. If C1 and C2 are subclasses of B which is a subclass of A, I need C1 and C2. Your answer returns B.